# In ec2 machine-cap staging deploy:setup giving a (Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Operation timed out - connect(2))

Tags: deployment, amazon-ec2, setup-deployment, gnome-terminal

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and i want to deploy in ec2 instance but the following error throws and unable to perform deploy process

krs@ubuntu:~/a/anonymous-ui-deploy$ cap staging deploy:setup

triggering load callbacks

- 2013-07-24 11:19:15 executing `staging'

  triggering start callbacks for `deploy:setup'

  - 2013-07-24 11:19:15 executing `multistage:ensure'
  - 2013-07-24 11:19:15 executing `deploy:setup'
  - executing "mkdir -p /home/ec2-user/apps/ano_stag /home/ec2-user/apps/ano_stag/releases /home/ec2-user/apps/ano_stag/shared /home/ec2-user/apps/ano_stag/shared/system /home/ec2-user/apps/ano_stag/shared/log /home/ec2-user/apps/ano_stag/shared/pids"

servers: ["ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com"]
connection failed for: ec2-user@ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com (Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Connection timed out - connect(2))

Please do let me know the answer for this problem to resolve. Thanks in advance

Comment: Which OS are you using, is it a ubuntu or Amazon linux? Depending upon your user name should change.Also make sure your ssh-agent is working properly, unless ssh-agent responds cap cant connect to your ec2 instance

Comment: i am using amazon linux

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a problem in connection with your servers, one of which is not allowing the other one to talk to.

1. Make sure you are able to connect to the destination server from the source server.
2. If not, then ensure the security group of the destination server has an inbound rule to allow ssh access - please see [this link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html#authorizing-access-to-an-instance-ssh) for more information.
3. Ensure that the destination server does not contain a firewall which blocks an incoming connection.
4. Verify the `syslog` on both the server and confirm that everything is good.